# (NASM) (80x86) Bootloader NEEDS xor ax, ax

Tags: x86, nasm, bootloader

I am learning how to make a bootloader from osdev. I'm using NASM to assemble my code, and a x86 machine to run my bootloader. This is a little piece of code which prints a character and enter in a infinite loop:

```
BITS 16

xor ax, ax

mov ah, 0x0E
mov al, 0x41
int 0x10

jmp $

times 510-($-$$) db 0x00
db 0x55
db 0xAA
```

My question is: why doesn't the code run when I comment the 'xor ax, ax' instruction? As you can see in the code above, the ax value is changed to store the interrupt parameters, so the code should run without the xor instruction...

Extra notes:

- I'm assembly the code under Xubuntu with this command:
  nasm -f bin -o main.bin main.asm
- I'm storing the 512-bytes machine code onto a pen drive with this command:
  sudo dd if=main.bin of=/dev/sdb
- My computer is able to start from a pen drive

Thank you so much.

Comment: Usually you'll have `org 0x7c00` at the top of the bootloader file and after `xor ax, ax` you copy it to _DS_ register and _ES_ if necessary (doesn't hurt) with `mov ds, ax` and `mov es, ax` after `xor ax, ax`. `xor ax, ax` is the pretty much the same as zeroing out _AX_. Since you overwrite AH and AL right after it shouldn't matter if `xor ax,ax` is done or not. You sure it works different with and without? Should also consider setting up _SS:SP_ (stack segment and pointer)

Comment: The only other possibility is that your BIOS is overwriting (blindly) what it thinks is the BPB which is often found at the beginning of a bootloader (usually right after a JMP instruction). If it is blindly updating your bootloader it could be that the modifications the BIOS makes after your code is loaded in RAM is causing your code to behave improperly.

Comment: I do recommend you consider doing `xor bx, bx` before _int 10h/ah=0eh_ since _BH_ is suppose to be the page number to write to (set it to 0).

Comment: When I don't comment the XOR instruction, the code is executed. When I comment it, the code isn't executed (it is "ignored") and the OS (Xubuntu) start.

Comment: I added mov bx, 0x00 instruction and it doesn't solve the problem (you were right, I forget to write it).

Comment: I'd be curious if this code with `xor ax,ax` works: http://www.capp-sysware.com/misc/stackoverflow/39240353/boot.asm

Comment: This code works, but it needs the xor instruction too... It's strange, I think

Comment: Okay now try that same code (the one I wrote) and comment the `xor ax,ax` out. Does it still work?

Comment: Ehmmm it works!! I don't understand the reason. Could you explain it?

Comment: More about the BIOS Parameter Blocks can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_parameter_block) . The `xor ax,ax` shouldn't be necessary at all in a working bootloader. Real hardware has strange quirks that you often won't see with virtual environments like bochs, qemu, virtualbox etc.

Comment: So, I should write this block of data on all my codes, right?

Comment: It appears you need to place that at the top of any bootsectors you write.

Comment: Ok. Thankyou very much!!!!

Comment: You may want to get a second opinion on the #osdev IRC channel here: https://kiwiirc.com/client/irc.freenode.net/#osdev . At this point I am only making an educated guess. Someone else may have encountered this before.

Comment: You can put a `hlt` inside your infinite loop to save power while you look at the screen before rebooting.  Also, it might be interesting to try your bootloaders in a virtual environment like BOCHS (which has a built-in debugger, so you'll definitely want to use it while developing stuff before trying on real hardware.  Being able to examine registers in a debugger goes *way* beyond just shortening the build/test/edit cycle.)  But yes, real BIOSes may behave differently from the BIOS of the machine BOCHS emulates.

Comment: Weird that nobody pointed out the fact that's it's way better to use a virtual machine (like VirtualBox) or at least an emulator (like Bochs) instead of testing the code in an actual machine....

Comment: @RyanB : See Peter's answer. He did. Was also mentioned in the IRC chat. I hinted at the idea when I mentioned "Real hardware has strange quirks that you often won't see with virtual environments like bochs, qemu, virtualbox etc." but it may have been a bit obtuse as a hint.

Answer (score 3):

In *theory* you wouldn't need a [BPB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_parameter_block) when writing a [MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) and not a [VBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_boot_record)<sup>1</sup>, and the presence of the `xor ax, ax` instruction wouldn't influence the booting.
You should include a `xor bh, bh` however (more on [Int 10/AH=0Eh](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0106.htm))

---

**Sadly this is just theory.**

Specially for USB devices a BPB is implicitly assumed by some firmware, including the full FDC descriptor (with a valid OS name).
Many thanks to [Michael Petch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39240353/nasm-80x86-bootloader-needs-xor-ax-ax/39248323?noredirect=1#comment65838265_39248323) for stressing this out.

Since the introduction of [UEFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) implementations, particularly the parts dealing with [CSM (Compatibility Support Module)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#CSM_booting), i.e. legacy booting, writing a fully supported MBR has became tricky.

The firmware will sometimes try to automatically detect what boot mode to use and since all UEFI devices are also legacy devices per specification, the firmware must rely on some quirk to tell them apart.

My firmware detect a device as "legacy", even when *explicitly* told so, **only** when at least one of these is true:

- There is a bootable, non empty, partition in the MBR partition table.
  The starting/ending address, either in CHS or LBA, are not checked at all.
- The first instruction is a `xor ax, ax` (in either forms: `33 C0` or `31 C0`).
  This is because the first thing most bootloaders do is to set the segment registers to zero through *AX*.

There may be other "signatures", like a jump at the first bytes, but I haven't tested them (yet).

If the firmware fails to detect the device as legacy and it is not a UEFI compliant device, it will be skipped.

---

You can use the `xor ax, ax` (in which case I suggest using of `db 33h, 0c0h` and a comment for documentation) or by adding a dummy partition entry, as shown below.

```
BITS 16
ORG 7c00h                       ;Soon or later you'll need this

 xor bh, bh
 mov ah, 0x0E
 mov al, 0x41
 int 0x10

_loop:
 hlt                            ;Be eco-friendly
jmp _loop

 ;Pad to the first PTE (Partition Table Entry), it is at 1beh
 TIMES 01beh-($-$$) db 00h

 dd 80h                         ;Bootable partition at CHS 0:0:0 (Which is illegal but not checked)
 db 01h                         ;Non empty partition (Type 1 is MS-DOS 2.0 FAT)

 ;Pad to the end of the sector minus 2
 TIMES 510-($-$$) db 00h
 dw 0aa55h                      ;Signature
```

---

<sup>1</sup> According to the parameters of the `dd` command.

Comment: Haha, I'd upvote a second time for the eco-friendly comment :)

Comment: It is false to believe you don't need a BPB. You probably don't use much real hardware, but during USB booting many BIOSes will write the drive geometry of the media (as the BIOS sees it) into the BPB area. If you have code where the BIOS thinks the BPB is, some BIOSes will blindly write to the area with the assumption the BPB is there. Other BIOSes will attempt to check to see if the first instruction of the USB device is a JMP instruction (some are dumb and don't even check if it was a 2 or 3 byte encoding). If a JMP is found the BIOS assumes there is a BPB and writes to that area.

Comment: Of course if a BIOS blindly writes over your code the behavior can be undefined. As the OP found out on the #OSdev forum (for a second opinion) this type of thing isn't unheard of. The OP also made mention that his code will work even if he uses an `sti` instruction instead of `xor ax,ax`.

Comment: And one other situation that mentioned was that some BIOSes may insists on an OEM NAME being present.

Comment: Of course these are all on top of the case you bring up about an active/bootable partition being marked in what the BIOS thinks is a partition table as well as signatures (byte(s) sequence) to clue the BIOS into thinking there is bootable legacy media.

Comment: @MichaelPetch My introduction was meant to show how things should work in a perfect world. A MBR don't need a BPB in a perfect world, even in an USB drive. Or does it?

Comment: Unfortunately we don't live in a perfect world. Far from it. In a perfect world it wouldn't require it. USB booting specifically is a problematic affair and often one has to take a more pragmatic approach to be compatible with the widest range of hardware :(

Answer (score 2):

Its 2018 and I have stumbled upon this same problem. Micheal's answers and comments seem to be the best solution yet. We don't live in a perfect world and that's just how it is. This is why I wanted to develop a BIOS when I started OS Dev. I hate to run someone else's code in my computer without examining it. But that's just too hard in case of Firmwares and BIOSes. It might even brick your PC if you mess with the BIOS without knowing what you're doing.

Anyway, I have just added this comment in case someone else stumbles upon this same problem later. I would seriously suggest to examine the source code and/or reverse engineer some already available bootloaders like GRUB, Windows Boot Manager, LILO etc. You can also download live USB linux distros for your PC, install it in a flash drive and look at the boot sector code in a Hex Editor and maybe even disassemble it.

This isn't exactly an answer to the question but its worth a mention. To make this more relevant all I can say is that I have reversed GRUB's code, as installed on Kali Linux USB bootable and it starts with a `XOR BP, BP` instruction.

Comment: Is there any way to get BIOS machine code? It would be helpful

Comment: Afaik you can certainly read the eeprom/equivalent if you have the correct software. PS - Sry for late reply. I didn't have commenting privileges earlier.