# Bootloader does not work on actual computer

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, bootloader, bare-metal

I know this question has been asked before, but none of the other answers seem to have solved my problem. Maybe I missed something?

I know the .iso works because I ran it in QEMU and it worked successfully. So what am I doing wrong?

```
bits 16

xor ax, ax

start:
    cld               ; Set direction flag to forward

    ; Set up registers
    mov ax, 07c0h     ; Segment location which BIOS loads
    add ax, 288       ; (4096 + 512) / 16 bytes
    mov ss, ax        ; Sets stack segment register
    mov sp, 4096      ; Sets stack pointer register (offset of stack)

    mov ax, 07c0h
    mov ds, ax        ; Sets data segment to where we're loaded

    mov si, text      ; Puts string into source index
    call print_string ; Calls print string

    jmp $             ; Infinite loop to prevent shutdown

print_string:
    mov ah, 0eh       ; System call for printing
    xor bh, bh        ; Sets BH register to 0

.repeat:
    lodsb             ; Loads byte into AL
    cmp al, 0         ; Sees if AL is 0
    je .done          ; Jumps to done if AL is zero

    int 10h           ; Otherwise, print
    jmp .repeat       ; Repeat

.done:
    ret

text db 'Test', 0

times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0 ; Pads 510 - (current location - start location) zeros
dw 0xAA55                 ; Standard PC boot signature (takes up 2 bytes)
```

Edit: I've added the following to my code:

```
xor ax, ax
cld
xor bh, bh
```

For creating an iso, I run the following commands:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=floppy.img bs=1024 count=1440
dd if=bootloader.bin of=floppy.img seek=0 count=1 conv=notrunc
mkdir iso
cp floppy.img iso/
mkisofs -o file.iso -b floppy.img iso
```

For burning the iso to my usb, I run the following commands:

```
umount /dev/sdX
dd if=/home/mint/Downloads/file.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=4M && sync
```

Comment: What exactly are you doing to boot your ".iso" on an actual computer?

Comment: You may wish to set the direction flag forward with _CLD_ since you rely on forward direction with _LODSB_. You can't guarantee what direction is set by the BIOS prior to reaching your coe.

Comment: For [Int 10h/ah=0eh](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0106.htm) you may want to set the BH register to 0 since that is used as the page number to write to.

Comment: When you boot did you use a CD-ROM? (I ask because you mention you made an ISO, but it is unclear if on the real PC you had burned a physical CD). I'd be curious what your command line for launching QEMU happens to look like.

Comment: @RossRidge All I did was burn my iso onto my usb. I made sure the boot via usb option in the BIOS was enable.

Comment: Real hardware, special with EFI CSM, do additional checks: [maybe this question will help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39240353/nasm-80x86-bootloader-needs-xor-ax-ax/39248323#39248323)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the "iso" you created is an optical disc image. It's bootable on a real computer only when its burned to an optical disc (eg. a CD-R). When you're using it with QEMU you're apparently using it as an emulated CD-ROM. When you copy it to your USB drive it's not in the correct format for booting on a USB drive.

Fortunately the correct format for booting off an USB drive is simple: your bootloader just needs to be on the first sector of the drive, just like on floppy or a hard disk. So you can skip the creating an "iso" part, and just write the boot sector directly to the USB drive. For example:

```
dd if=bootloader.bin of=/dev/sdX
```

Comment: Perhaps the OP was confused by the fact that "hybrid" ISO images are now common for Linux "live cd" images: you can `dd` them to USB devices, because they look like a valid partition table as well as looking like a bootable ISO9660 image, and syslinux 3.72 and later support booting from this.    ([This blog briefly mentions some of that](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/iso2usb) but is mostly about just using the `isohybrid` command.)