# Helloworld Bootloader over USB (NOT Floppy nor CD-ROM nor Emulator) using terminal

Tags: unix, assembly, bootloader, usb-drive, dd

I am newbie to bootloaders, I read tens of articles about bootleaders but it seems that no one is running for me.

They all mention the traditional steps:

- `umount`
- `dd`
- `sync`

the same as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372607/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-from-terminal)

let me first tell you that using `unetbootin`, I tried [TinyCore Linux](http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/install.html) and it worked perfectly. Then I tried to run it from terminal by converting it from ISOLINUX into SYSLINUX using `isohybrid` tool in addition to `dd` tool, it works too.

Next, I tried to make just a boot-loader using assembly code that prints out a "Hello world" on screen. Of course, I started with something working like [MikeOS](http://mikeos.sourceforge.net/write-your-own-os.html).

What I have done as a root is the following:

- Format the flash memory with FAT32: `mkdosfs -n 'USB-Drive-Name' -I /dev/sdb -F 32`
- Make sure it is unmounted `umount /dev/sdb*` where `/dev/sdb` is my USB drive.
- Assemble the code: `nasm -f bin -o myfirst.bin myfirst.asm`
- Install it into MBR of the USB: `dd if=myfirst.bin of=/dev/sdb bs=512`.
- `sync`
- Reboot

Noting that I didn't install any kernel, I expect to get a "Hello world" during boot but I what I am getting is "No Operating System".

Is there something I have missed?

Let me talk about this [assembly code](https://gist.github.com/YouriAckx/a52010a05a430496ae11):

```
;----------------------------------------------;
;
; A minimal bootloader that prints a hello world
; then halts.
;
; nasm -f bin hello-boot.asm -o hello-boot.bin
;
; @YouriAckx
;
;----------------------------------------------;

                org        0x7c00               ; BIOS loads at this address

                bits       16                   ; 16 bits real mode

; Print a welcome message.
; We have no DOS nor Linux kernel here.
; Therefore, we will use bios int 0x10.

start:
                cli                             ; disable interrupts

                mov     si, msg                 ; SI points to message
                mov     ah, 0x0e                ; print char service
.loop           lodsb                           ; AL <- [DS:SI] && SI++
                or      al, al                  ; end of string?
                jz      halt
                int     0x10                    ; print char
                jmp     .loop                   ; next char

halt:           hlt                             ; halt


msg:            db        "Hello, World!", 0


;----------------------------------------------;
; Bootloader signature must be located
; at bytes #511 and #512.
; Fill with 0 in between.
; $  = address of the current line
; $$ = address of the 1st instruction
;----------------------------------------------;

                times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
                dw        0xaa55
```

Comment: You need to show us your boot loader so we can tell you what is wrong with it.

Comment: I am not sure that the wrong is in the bootloader itself but probably with the installation. For instance, I tried https://github.com/ishanthilina/USB-FAT32-Bootloader

Comment: and this one: https://gist.github.com/YouriAckx/a52010a05a430496ae11

Comment: Try to set `bx` to zero before invoking `int 0x10`, otherwise output may not appear. Also try setting up `ah` every time in the loop, not sure if `int 0x10` destroys it.

Comment: And please paste that code into your question as required by the site rules.

Comment: Ok, I added the simple one: Hello world code.

Comment: Note, even if it will boot it might not work because you don't initialize `DS` to a known value. You are correct that the code is loaded at physical address `7c00` but that can be `0:7c00` or `7c0:0` and that's just for `CS`, `DS` may be something else entirely.

Comment: Unless you are using a pre-UEFI firmware, it won't' boot a device unless they recognise some common code pattern. [One is `xor ax, ax`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39248323/5801661) another is a `jmp ...` that skips the BPB (that the firmware may attempt to patch!). A bootable partition, even fake, may be needed. Also, you don't need to format the device with a FAT FS just to destroy it with a custom MBR with no partition table (just *dd* it).

Comment: Thank you @MargaretBloom, I will take your notes into consideration in my programming from now on.

Comment: @Jester Thank you too.

Comment: It is solved after adding your suggestions.